# Convert time in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

Here is how the time shows in the database right now:

2016-05-07 21:18:21

Right now, this is how it does to convert it:

```
function time_elapsed_string($datetime) {
$now = new DateTime;
$ago = new DateTime($datetime);
$diff = $now->diff($ago);

$diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
$diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

$string = array(
    'y' => 'year',
    'm' => 'month',
    'w' => 'week',
    'd' => 'day',
    'h' => 'hour',
    'i' => 'minute',
    's' => 'second',
);
foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
    if ($diff->$k) {
        $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
    } else {
        unset($string[$k]);
    }
}

$string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}
```

when I do this it converts everything. BUT i want it to only show however many seconds, however many minutes, however many hours and if it's 24 hours, then it's 1 day, and 1 day. everything else I want it to show in this format: F j, Y g:ia

Comment: Can you elaborate. What do you mean by "Just show the number 1, not 2 weeks..." Also, what have you tried?

Comment: i just edited op. sorry about that

Comment: I think I have an idea. If you get the diff in days. If(diff>=1){ echo "one day"} esleif(diff>=7){ echo "one week" } esleif(diff>=30){ echo "one month" }.... sorry for dumping code here but give it a try, didn't want to make it an answer as I'm not sure this is what you wanted

Comment: Wait... the if's need to be the other way around. First compare against 30 then 7 then 1. Otherwise 1 will always be true

Comment: @Andreas yes you have the idea but i want it to only show however many seconds, however many minutes, however many hours and if it's 24 hours, then it's 1 day, and 1 day. everything else I want it to show in this format: F j, Y g:ia

Comment: You wrote month, week, day before. But I believe you can use the same way for hours too

Comment: @Andreas what do you mean? i dont think you understand my question

Comment: From edit history: `BUT I want it to show 1 day ago if 1 day ago, 1 week ago if 1 week ago, and 1 month ago if 1 month ago. Just show the number 1, not 2 weeks...`

Comment: @Andreas, yes i meant to show add the hours in there

Comment: Ok.. in that case diff in days should be 0. So in the case 0 you just create a new diff with the diff hours.

Comment: @Andreas What do you mean? can you create an answer?

Comment: https://www.freelancer.com/projects/php/php-convert-timestamp-date/

Comment: @johnjay22113 Can you please share full code with file. so i can understand what exactly want & solutions for that.

Comment: @johnjay22113 you want to exactly like this result pls see screenshot link.
http://prntscr.com/b1kr87

Comment: @johnjay22113  Please see screenshot of solutions http://prntscr.com/b1kznl

Comment: @TanmayPatel hi sorry i got it already. i just did strpos with if statement. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Format a unix timestamp in a 'time ago' format,
 * e.g. 15 minutes ago or 7 days ago.
 *
 * @param  integer $time
 * @return string
 */
function ago($time)
{
    $config = array(
        array('second',  'seconds'),
        array('minute',  'minutes'),
        array('hour',    'hours'),
        array('day',     'days'),
        array('week',    'weeks'),
        array('month',   'months'),
        array('year',    'years'),
        array('decade',  'decades'),
    );

    list($periods, $lengths, $now) = array($config, [60, 60, 24, 7, 4.35, 12, 10], time());
    $difference = $now - $time;
    for ($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] and $j < count($lengths) - 1; $j++)
    {
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    }
    $difference = round($difference);
    $period = $difference == 1 ? $periods[$j][0] : $periods[$j][1];
    if ($difference == 0)
    {
        return 'Just now';
    }

    return "${difference} ${period} ago";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$old_date = "2016-05-07 21:18:21";
$date311 = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($old_date));
$date31 = date_create($date311);
//creating a date object
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
$date411 = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
$date41 = date_create($date411);
//calculating the difference between dates
//the dates must be provided to the function as date objects that's why we were setting them 
//as date objects and not just as strings
//date_diff returns an date object wich can be accessed as seen below
$diff341 = date_diff($date41, $date31);

//accesing days
$days1 = $diff341->d;
//accesing months
$months1 = $diff341->m;
//accesing years
$years1 = $diff341->y;
//accesing hours
$hours1=$diff341->h;
//accesing minutes
$minutes1=$diff341->i;
//accesing seconds
$seconds1=$diff341->s;

echo '<center>';
echo '<br /><div style="background-color:green;color:#fff;padding:10px;width:600px;font-size:16px">
<b>The difference between '.$date311.' and '.$date411.' 
<br />is: ' . $years1 . ' year(s), ' . $months1 . ' month(s), '. $days1 . ' day(s), '.$hours1.' hour(s),
'.$minutes1.' minute(s), '.$seconds1.' second(s) </b>
</div><br />';
echo '</center>';
```

### Result :-

[image]